# After passing the value from JavaScript to C#, how to do some automatic operation with it?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am doing a charging system. The API for the customers to pay for the goods runs in JavaScript:

```
function jsApiCall()
{
   WeixinJSBridge.invoke(
   'getBrandWCPayRequest',
   <%=wxJsApiParam%>,
    function (res)
    {
        WeixinJSBridge.log(res.err_msg);
        //alert(res.err_code + res.err_desc + res.err_msg);
        switch(res.err_msg)
        {
            case 'get_brand_wcpay_request:cancel':
                document.getElementById("Hidden1").value=1; 
                alert('payment canceled!');     
                break;
            case 'get_brand_wcpay_request:fail':         
                document.getElementById("Hidden1").value=2; 
                alert('payment failed!');
                break;
            case 'get_brand_wcpay_request:ok':     
                document.getElementById("Hidden1").value=3; 
                alert('payment successful!');
                break;
        }
     }
    );
}
```

and I use the following to get the corresponding value from **jsApiCall()**.

```
<input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" runat="server" />
```

I need to append some information into a text file in the server right after I get the value of **Hidden1.Value** but should not require customers to click any buttons or do any operations. Where should I write the following back-end code? Thanks.

```
string rst = Hidden1.Value;
switch (rst)
{
    case "1":        
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("1");
        }
        break;
    case "2":
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("2");
        }
        break;
    case "3":
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("3");
        }
        break;
    default:
        Response.Write("failed to update .txt file");
        break;
}
```

In summary, what I want is to record some information in the server right after a successful payment by any customer. If this approach doesn't work, I also appreciate if anyone can give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write a function on the js side - this function will be responsible for taking the value from the client then submit to server.

To submit the value to the server you have 2 options (based on your needs):
- Having the hidden input inside a form and force that form to submit from inside your new js function.
- Make your js function call the server method directly through an ajax call

Calling this new js function can be done within your `switch(res.err_msg)` or on
 the [onchange event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) of the hidden input.

Example:

```
function (res)
    {
        WeixinJSBridge.log(res.err_msg);
        //alert(res.err_code + res.err_desc + res.err_msg);
        switch(res.err_msg)
        {
            case 'get_brand_wcpay_request:cancel':
                document.getElementById("Hidden1").value=1; 
                mySubmitToServer(1);
                alert('payment canceled!');     
                break;
            case 'get_brand_wcpay_request:fail':         
                document.getElementById("Hidden1").value=2; 
                mySubmitToServer(2);
                alert('payment failed!');
                break;
            case 'get_brand_wcpay_request:ok':     
                document.getElementById("Hidden1").value=3; 
                mySubmitToServer(3);
                alert('payment successful!');
                break;
        }
     }
    );
}

function mySubmitToServer(valToSubmit)
{
   // submit the form
   // OR
   // ajax call to server method
}
<form >
<input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" runat="server" />
</form>
```